# How to install php7.2-curl without uninstalling libcurl3 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04, php

I'm using a software that comes with a separate php and that php has php-fpm that requires libcurl3, but php7.2-curl requires libcurl4. When I run `sudo apt install php7.2-curl` the command uninstalls the libcurl3 package, and when I install libcurl3 the php7.2-curl package is uninstalled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have both libcurl3 and libcurl4 installed at same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061431/how-to-have-both-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-installed-at-same-time)