# I get stuck to install xrtream ui

Tags: 14.04, 18.04

Where is the problem? I have ubuntu 18.04.  I just type `MAIN` and click ten on enter but it gives me syntax error. But how???
Here is what i want to install

```
wget https://xtream-ui.com/install/install.py ; sudo python install.py
```

`
Then it asks me to choose

```
Installation Type [MAIN, LB]:
```

and i must type `MAIN`  yep? I do so but it returnes me error called:

```
 │         Invalid installation type        │
```

[image: please see the picture]

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release details (you've tagged two very different releases though - please clarify), and please don't provide pictures of text; it's easier to read & we can copy/paste and use text when provided as text in responses to you (we can't for pictures of text)

Comment: i have 18.04 and want to install xtream ui but here is problem with syntax. Please see:

 Installation Type [MAIN, LB]: MAIN

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │         Invalid installation type        │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘


root@ubuntu:~#   Installation Type [MAIN, LB]: MAIN
Installation: command not found

Comment: it asks me:  Installation Type [MAIN, LB]:

Than i type ''MAIN'' and it returns me error. but why?????

Comment: i provided please see

Comment: You still have 14.04 listed, but you wget one file, then execute something different to that which you downloaded (can't copy file that was downloaded - it's still in picture).  Your provided text commands do **not** match the picture you provided  (you did not download `install.py`)

Answer (score 0):

I've started installation in the next way for 19.10:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install python2.7
sudo apt install apache2
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libcurl4 libgeoip-dev python -y
wget https://xtream-ui.com/install/install.py
```

Edit `install.py` and change `libcurl3` to `libcurl4`

```
sudo python2.7 install.py
```

But during installation I got the next error, you could not get if you try:

```
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │             Installing libpng            │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/libpng12.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/libpng12.deb
```

But it is for the next question.

Changing `libcurl3` to `libcurl4` is not the right way, but only experiment to see if the installation will go forward in case of this manipulation.

The full installation log:

```
Installation Type [MAIN, LB]: MAIN

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │          Start installation? Y/N         │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

  Y

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │          Preparing Installation          │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │      Removing libcurl4 if installed      │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │            Installing libcurl4           │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │          Installing libgeoip-dev         │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │          Installing libxslt1-dev         │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │           Installing e2fsprogs           │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │              Installing wget             │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │             Installing mcrypt            │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │              Installing nscd             │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │              Installing htop             │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │          Installing mysql-server         │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │             Installing libpng            │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/libpng12.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/libpng12.deb
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │         Creating user xtreamcodes        │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │           Downloading Software           │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 


 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │            Installing Software           │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │             Configuring MySQL            │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │        Enter MySQL Root Password:        │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

  Password

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │   Drop existing & create database? Y/N   │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

  y 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │               Encrypting...              │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │            Configuring System            │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │              Modifying Nginx             │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │           Starting Xtream Codes          │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

/home/xtreamcodes/iptv_xtream_codes/php/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
start-stop-daemon: matching on world-writable pidfile /home/xtreamcodes/iptv_xtream_codes/php/VaiIb8.pid is insecure
start-stop-daemon: matching on world-writable pidfile /home/xtreamcodes/iptv_xtream_codes/php/JdlJXm.pid is insecure
start-stop-daemon: matching on world-writable pidfile /home/xtreamcodes/iptv_xtream_codes/php/CWcfSP.pid is insecure
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │                                          │ 
 │                                          │ 
 │          Installation completed!         │ 
 │                                          │ 
 │                                          │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │    Admin UI: http://192.168.1.3:25500    │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │     Please store your MySQL password!    │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │             KOfH2GObqjEEkyNh             │ 
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But it does not work by Admin UI: http://192.168.1.3:25500

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0
```

If you could not install `libcurl3`, you could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061431/how-to-have-both-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-installed-at-same-time) solution and try installation with `libcurl3`.

Comment: thanks, i can see now admin panel but i can not loggin, admin/admin doesn not work. i try to update username and password with following command:

UPDATE xtream_iptvpro.reg_users SET password='$6$rounds=20000$xtreamcodes$XThC5OwfuS0YwS4ahiifzF14vkGbGsFF1w7ETL4sRRC5sOrAWCjWvQJDromZUQoQuwbAXAFdX3h3Cp3vqulpS0' WHERE id='1';

but i gte followinf error:

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xtream_iptvpro.reg_users' doesn't exist

Comment: maybe table name have been changed in your release or have not been created because of an error. You need to list all your tables and see what tables you have in your xtream database. But it is the next question you could ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/