# Several packages removed during installation after uninstalling libcurl4

Tags: apt, system-installation, curl

Since I had issues installing curl on Ubuntu 18.04, I have executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove -y libcurl4
```

Followed by this one:

```
sudo apt install -y libcurl4 curl
```

What I do not understand is that during the install process (not during the uninstall), the following were also removed:

```
Removing mongodb-org (4.0.23) ...
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.23) ...
Removing r-base (3.6.3-1xenial) ...
Removing r-recommended (3.6.3-1xenial) ...
Removing r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-2xenial0) ...
Removing r-cran-boot (1.3-27-1.1604.0) ...
Removing obs-studio (25.0.8-0obsproject1~xenial) ...
Removing r-base-dev (3.6.3-1xenial) ...
Removing r-base-html (3.6.3-1xenial) ...
Removing r-cran-class (7.3-18-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-cluster (2.1.1-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-codetools (0.2-18-1cran1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-foreign (0.8.76-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-kernsmooth (2.23-18-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-mgcv (1.8-33-1cran1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-nlme (3.1.152-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-rpart (4.1-15-2xenial0) ...
Removing r-cran-survival (3.2-10-1cran1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-matrix (1.3-2-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-lattice (0.20-41-1cran1xenial0) ...
Removing r-cran-mass (7.3-53.1-1.1604.0) ...
Removing r-cran-nnet (7.3-15-1.1604.0) ...
Removing virtualbox-5.2 (5.2.44-139111~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Removing r-base-core (3.6.3-1xenial) ...
Removing libcurl3:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu2) ...
```

Do these correspond to packages no longer used? R no longer works?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have both libcurl3 and libcurl4 installed at same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061431/how-to-have-both-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-installed-at-same-time)

Comment: Consider not supplying the `-y` option if you are unsure what the outcome is going to be.

Comment: The list of packages removed does NOT correspond to  "no longer used". The list corresponds to packages that *you ordered apt to remove* in order to install libcurl3. Anything that uses libcurl 4 is now broken.

Comment: Did you actually run `sudo apt install -y libcurl3 curl` as seems likely, and as previous comments have assumed?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is clearly related, and one or other of its answers may be what *should have* been done but it offers no help resolving or explaining the actual scenario described in the post here

Answer (score 0):

The command removed many packages, and need to be installed one by one again.

Yes I know it is difficult but there is no way back (Or untill for time).

The only thing you can do is to not use `-y` without being sure about what you are doing.

If you don't use `-y`, it will ask you for a conformation with a sentence telling how much disk space will be used (in case of installation) or how much space will be freed (in case of uninstallation).

Comment: I agree; and imho the `-y` flag should never be used unless one is setting up some unattended installation whose details are known in advance. But, assuming OP installed libcurl3 in place of libcurl4, substitute packages may have been installed, and reinstalling the removed packages might be very difficult (installing libcurl4 if it wasn't installed may be needed?). This is probably an example of a irreversible package management action.